# How to submit django ModelForm from template

Tags: django, django-models, chat, modelform

I am trying to create instances of

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text        = models.TextField()
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sender      = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_sent')
    receiver    = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_received')
```

when users try to message other users. I have a form

```
<form action="{% url 'chat:submit_message' viewed_user.username %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="" />
    <label for="message">Enter your message here</label><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and the "sender" is stored in the 'request.user', and "receiver" is carried as 'username' in

```
url(r'^message/(?P<username>\w+)/$',        views.message
```

I tried

```
def send_message(request, username):
    """Add a new comment."""
    # p = request.POST
    print request
    message = Message()
    m = request.POST
    mf = MessageForm(m, instance=message)    
    text    = request.POST['message']
    sender  = User.objects.get(username=username)
    receiver= request.user
    mf.fields["text"] = text
    mf.fields["sender"] = sender
    mf.fields["receiver"] = receiver
    mf.save()
```

and got complaints of

```
`AttributeError at /chat/message/[username]/submit/
'unicode' object has no attribute 'widget'`
```

How do I create messages when form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which will work:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['text']

@login_required
def send_message(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message(sender=request.user,
                          receiver=get_object_or_404(User, username=username))
        form = MessageForm(request.POST, instance=message)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            # handle the invalid form here if you want
    return redirect('some-view')
```

Note that the field name is the `text` but not the `message` so you need to update the html form with valid field name.